# I am not able to populate Javafx TableView using fxml

Tags: mysql, javafx, fxml

Nothing seems to wrong with the code but the table is not populating.Same code is working well with other place.

```
public class Test implements Initializable {
@FXML
TableView sort_view;
@FXML
TableColumn sort_id, sort_pname, sort_price, sort_quantity, sort_total;
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    final ObservableList<Sort> data =
            FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    Sort sort;
    SalesDb db = new SalesDb();
    ResultSet rs = db.sortProduct();

    try {
        while (rs.next()) {
            int id = rs.getInt("ID");
            String productName = rs.getString("ProductName");
            String productPrice = rs.getString("ProductPrice");
            String quantity = rs.getString("Quantity");
            String total = rs.getString("Total");

            sort = new Sort(Integer.toString(id),productName,productPrice,quantity,total);
            data.add(sort);
            System.out.println(sort.getId()+","+sort.getProductName()+","+sort.getPrice()+","+sort.getQuantity()+","+sort.getTotal());
        }
    }catch(Exception  e){
        System.out.println("There is an Exception.");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    sort_id.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Sort, String>("id"));
    sort_pname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Sort, String>("productName"));
    sort_price.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Sort, String>("price"));
    sort_quantity.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Sort, String>("quantity"));
    sort_total.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Sort, String>("total"));

    sort_view.getItems().add(data);


}
```

}

and my fxml file is as follows.

[image]

My Table is no populating, what could be the reason.
Table shows as follows..

[image]

please look into it whats the problem...

Comment: Are you sure this controller class is loaded? Place a break point in your codes to debug this.

Comment: Add a breakpoint after `data.add(sort)` and check whether there is anything in `data` to populate in the table

Comment: unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: wrong method for adding to table's items: you add the collection as one single item vs. all items of the collection (happens without error because your tableView is untyped ... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just caused not proper use of naming convention,because there were multiple item's
i had to use data.addAll(sort) instead of data.add(sort).